# Extracting Information from JSON Object - Android

Tags: android, json

I have a JSON feed where I need to extract the "product" information from it as shown below:  **UPDATED**

```
    {
    "category-key": "guvera-music",
    "category-localized-title": "Guvera music",
    "items": [
        {
            "type": "product",
            "product": {
                "engine-product-id": "com.guvera.nonrenewing.day",
                "localization-key": "guvera-1-day-pass",
                "type": "music.subscription",
                "localized-description": "Guvera 1 day pass",
                "category-key": "guvera-music",
                "denomination-currency": "IDR",
                "currency": "IDR",
                "product-promotion-message": "",
                "denomination-amount": 3000,
                "parent-category-id": null,
                "merchant": "Guvera",
                "price": 3300,
                "product-id": 1,
                "product-image-id": 19,
                "srp": 3300
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "product",
            "product": {
                "engine-product-id": "com.guvera.nonrenewing.week",
                "localization-key": "guvera-1-week-pass",
                "type": "music.subscription",
                "localized-description": "Guvera 1 week pass",
                "category-key": "guvera-music",
                "denomination-currency": "IDR",
                "currency": "IDR",
                "product-promotion-message": "",
                "denomination-amount": 20000,
                "parent-category-id": null,
                "merchant": "Guvera",
                "price": 22000,
                "product-id": 2,
                "product-image-id": 19,
                "srp": 22000
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "product",
            "product": {
                "engine-product-id": "com.guvera.nonrenewing.month",
                "localization-key": "guvera-1-month-pass",
                "type": "music.subscription",
                "localized-description": "Guvera 1 month pass",
                "category-key": "guvera-music",
                "denomination-currency": "IDR",
                "currency": "IDR",
                "product-promotion-message": "",
                "denomination-amount": 55000,
                "parent-category-id": null,
                "merchant": "Guvera",
                "price": 60500,
                "product-id": 3,
                "product-image-id": 19,
                "srp": 60500
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "product",
            "product": {
                "engine-product-id": "com.guvera.nonrenewing.trimester",
                "localization-key": "guvera-3-month-pass",
                "type": "music.subscription",
                "localized-description": "Guvera 3 month pass",
                "category-key": "guvera-music",
                "denomination-currency": "IDR",
                "currency": "IDR",
                "product-promotion-message": "",
                "denomination-amount": 165000,
                "parent-category-id": null,
                "merchant": "Guvera",
                "price": 181500,
                "product-id": 4,
                "product-image-id": 19,
                "srp": 181500
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "product",
            "product": {
                "engine-product-id": "com.guvera.nonrenewing.semester",
                "localization-key": "guvera-6-month-pass",
                "type": "music.subscription",
                "localized-description": "Guvera 6 month pass",
                "category-key": "guvera-music",
                "denomination-currency": "IDR",
                "currency": "IDR",
                "product-promotion-message": "",
                "denomination-amount": 303600,
                "parent-category-id": null,
                "merchant": "Guvera",
                "price": 333960,
                "product-id": 5,
                "product-image-id": 19,
                "srp": 333960
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "product",
            "product": {
                "engine-product-id": "com.guvera.nonrenewing.year",
                "localization-key": "guvera-12-month-pass",
                "type": "music.subscription",
                "localized-description": "Guvera 12 month pass",
                "category-key": "guvera-music",
                "denomination-currency": "IDR",
                "currency": "IDR",
                "product-promotion-message": "",
                "denomination-amount": 547800,
                "parent-category-id": null,
                "merchant": "Guvera",
                "price": 602580,
                "product-id": 6,
                "product-image-id": 19,
                "srp": 602580
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to use the following code but my code is not working so that I can get "product":

```
            try {
            JSONArray jsonProductArray = response.getJSONArray("items");

            // Parse through
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonProductArray.length(); i++) {
            // Is the code below correct so that I can get "product"? 
                JSONObject products = jsonProductArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("product");
            }
```

Is this JSON structure an Array with Objects inside? Or rather a single object containing an Array with 6 items? How could I isolate "product" on the code above? Any detailed information on how to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the content of your informations your response? because this is not really JSON

Comment: Not a valid JSON String, if JSON is created by you then share code from which u are generating posted JSON string

Comment: what you have written here is a response which appears on HTTP client program, this things used for human readable data, but you must have got the response in raw as well, copy that, raw is actual JSON

Comment: use GSON library that will make things easier for you

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you have pasted above is not a valid JSON.

To verify if your JSON is correct or not you can use [JSONLint](http://pro.jsonlint.com/).

> Is this JSON structure an Array with Objects inside? Or rather a single object containing an Array with 6 items?

Please note that if you have a JSON Array your JSON starts from `[` and ends with `]` i.e. Square brackets. Inside it you can have JSON objects.
If you have JSON object it will start from `{` and end with `}` i.e. Curly brackets.

**UPDATE:**

After you updated the question, the JSON is valid.
Now I suppose you want the `product` JSON object, for that you should see that it is inside the `items` JSON Array.

So you have to do something like this:

```
JSONArray jsonProductArray = response.getJSONArray("items");

JSONObject productObject=jsonProductArray.getJSONObject(2);
```

To get the objects inside the `product`

```
productObject.get("nameOfObject");
```

Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
JSONArray jsonProductArray = response.getJSONArray("items");

// Parse through
for (int i = 0; i < jsonProductArray.length(); i++) {
// Is the code below correct so that I can get "product"? 
JSONObject products = jsonProductArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject(1).getString("engine-product-id");
        }
```

Comment: Try this code and let me know your review about it :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to get `JSONObject` on root see below.

```
JSONObject j = new JSONObject(json);
```

Here json is your `json` file or String that you want to parse.

Then after you need to get `JSONArray` named `items` like shown below.

```
JSONArray a = j.getJSONArray("items");
```

Then loop through above `JSONArray` as show below.

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++){
   // Here you need to get JSONObject from JSONArray at Index i.
   JSONOject jj = a.getJSONObject(i);
   //Now you need to get product JSONObject
   JSONObject jsonObj = jj.getJSONObject("product");
   //From jsonObj you get all information about product.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gson library example to retrieve above json String,

you will require only one line to get all json data populated in your object, which is

```
        Response response = (new Gson()).fromJson("your_json_String", Response.class);
```

for this line to work add `**gson**` library to your project and add following classes

First make a `Product.java`

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Product {

    @SerializedName("engine-product-id")
    private String engine_product_id;

    @SerializedName("localization-key")
    private String localization_key;

    @SerializedName("type")
    private String type;

    @SerializedName("localized-description")
    private String localized_description;

    @SerializedName("category-key")
    private String category_key;

    @SerializedName("denomination-currency")
    private String denomination_currency;

    @SerializedName("currency")
    private String currency;

    @SerializedName("product-promotion-message")
    private String product_promotion_message;

    @SerializedName("denomination-amount")
    private String denomination_amount;

    @SerializedName("parent-category-id")
    private String parent_category_id;

    @SerializedName("merchant")
    private String merchant;

    @SerializedName("price")
    private String price;

    @SerializedName("product-id")
    private String product_id;

    @SerializedName("product-image-id")
    private String product_image_id;

    @SerializedName("srp")
    private String srp;

    public String getEngine_product_id() {
        return engine_product_id;
    }

    public void setEngine_product_id(String engine_product_id) {
        this.engine_product_id = engine_product_id;
    }

    public String getLocalization_key() {
        return localization_key;
    }

    public void setLocalization_key(String localization_key) {
        this.localization_key = localization_key;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getLocalized_description() {
        return localized_description;
    }

    public void setLocalized_description(String localized_description) {
        this.localized_description = localized_description;
    }

    public String getCategory_key() {
        return category_key;
    }

    public void setCategory_key(String category_key) {
        this.category_key = category_key;
    }

    public String getDenomination_currency() {
        return denomination_currency;
    }

    public void setDenomination_currency(String denomination_currency) {
        this.denomination_currency = denomination_currency;
    }

    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    public void setCurrency(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    public String getProduct_promotion_message() {
        return product_promotion_message;
    }

    public void setProduct_promotion_message(String product_promotion_message) {
        this.product_promotion_message = product_promotion_message;
    }

    public String getDenomination_amount() {
        return denomination_amount;
    }

    public void setDenomination_amount(String denomination_amount) {
        this.denomination_amount = denomination_amount;
    }

    public String getParent_category_id() {
        return parent_category_id;
    }

    public void setParent_category_id(String parent_category_id) {
        this.parent_category_id = parent_category_id;
    }

    public String getMerchant() {
        return merchant;
    }

    public void setMerchant(String merchant) {
        this.merchant = merchant;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getProduct_id() {
        return product_id;
    }

    public void setProduct_id(String product_id) {
        this.product_id = product_id;
    }

    public String getProduct_image_id() {
        return product_image_id;
    }

    public void setProduct_image_id(String product_image_id) {
        this.product_image_id = product_image_id;
    }

    public String getSrp() {
        return srp;
    }

    public void setSrp(String srp) {
        this.srp = srp;
    }
}
```

Now make Item.java

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Item {

    @SerializedName("type")
    private String type;

    @SerializedName("product")
    private String product;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(String product) {
        this.product = product;
    }
}
```

Finally make Response.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Response {

    @SerializedName("category-key")
    private String category_key;

    @SerializedName("category-localized-title")
    private String category_localized_title;

    @SerializedName("type")
    private ArrayList<Item> type;

    public String getCategory_key() {
        return category_key;
    }

    public void setCategory_key(String category_key) {
        this.category_key = category_key;
    }

    public String getCategory_localized_title() {
        return category_localized_title;
    }

    public void setCategory_localized_title(String category_localized_title) {
        this.category_localized_title = category_localized_title;
    }

    public ArrayList<Item> getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(ArrayList<Item> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```